How to store an Instant in a database (Oracle) with Hibernate/JPA
After reading different blogs and stackoverflow articles I still don't get it.
In my application I have an Instant and I want to store this instant in a database without messing around with it at all.
I use JPA (backed by Hibernate 5). I first tried to define the database column as TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE which is an art by itself because in Oracle it is called a "WITH ZONE" but then you can configure it as an offset by setting oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false ... oh well. After all I decided not to go this route.
The route I want to go is to store all my Instants as an Oracle TIMESTAMP which I (and my application) will implicitly assume to be in UTC. So in Oracle I have my column defined simply as a TIMESTAMP (without anything else).
So I assumed that if I use a LocalDateTime for the attribute in question it will simply be stored like this.
But surprise! The result depends on my setting of hibernate.jdbc.time_zone.
Why? A LocalDateTime is a LocalDateTime is a LocalDateTime. Why would anyone mess around with that? Why does Hibernate or Jdbc(?) change it? Why does it assume that the LocalDateTime has to do anything with the settings of my JVM?
So my question is: what is the best and most straight forward way to store an Instant without hibernate, jdbc or the database to mess around with it?
I'm close to persist it as an integer and store milliseconds...
[EDIT]
OK. I discovered that one problem was that in my application the property oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion was set to false. If it is set to true (the default) then I can store and read an Instant as expected!
I haven't really understood what this property is supposed to do. It was introduced by a team member because he did not want to store the timezone region in the TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE column. He only wanted the offset to be stored which (in my opinion) makes absolutely sense. Timezone information might be wrong and might change over time. And as we are actually interested in the Instant ("UTC") the region does not matter for us.
As I understand it Oracle always stores the time in UTC internally along with the region. If you set timezoneAsRegion to false then it only stores the offset. But somehow in combination with hibernate/jdbc this is messed up and the time is stored wrong on the database.
So the question is now: how can I store only the time offset in the TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE column and have hibernate/java behave correctly?
Thanks!
Oliver

Never tried the combination of Oracle and Hibernate. I should say that timestamp with zone should be the correct data type to use, though you may need to tell Hibernate explicitly how to convert your Instant to OffsetDateTime or ZonedDateTime before storing it.

If you give up, at least store your Instant as a varchar so that it’s readable. Instant.parse() parses the return value from Instant.toString() back, so the conversions are trivial. I still believe that there should be a way through, though.

Good article here: https://vladmihalcea.com/time-zones-java-web-application/

I can't find any Oracle documentation that even hints that "TIMESTAMP WITH ZONE" is correct. All the Oracle documentation I can find says "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE". Yes, lots of people write "... with zone" or "... with timezone" informally, but nothing suggests that is the correct type name. Admittedly I'm too lazy to test this but I have definitely written "... WITH TIME ZONE" many times.

See how to do it with pure jdbc here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/79017921/2388256
